# How to use go-sqlmock when I have concurrent query in my program?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-sqlmock

[sqlmock](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) needs to match the SQL in order. But if I have concurrent query in my code just like this:

```golang
    condition1 := make(map[string]string)
    condition2 := make(map[string]string)

    var count int64
    var user User
    var task Task

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

    wgDone := make(chan interface{})
    errCh := make(chan error)

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := conn.Where(condition1).Find(&user).Error
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }(&wg)

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := conn.Where(condition2).Find(&task).Error
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }(&wg)

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := conn.Count(&count).Error
        if err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }(&wg)
    
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(wgDone)
    }()

    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        return err
    case <-wgDone:
        break
    }
    
    ...
```

It is said that we can't know the execution order of the SQL. So I dont't know how to use sqlmock to match the sql correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MatchExpectationsInOrder`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#SqlmockCommon) method disables in-order checking for exactly this scenario.